# My top panel moved up about half of its height, how pull it down?

Tags: wingpanel

I can only see the bottom half of my top panel now. How can I move it down to its original location?

Comment: Do you mean a window or the wingpanel?

Comment: @DanielRöhrig wingpanel (the thing with date, time, battery percentage).

Comment: That's odd. But it could be a problem with your monitor or graphics card. Maybe try to recalibrate your monitor or have a look at your graphics card tool/system preferences.

Comment: might have accidentally tapped it if you have a touchscreen: you can actually move the freya panel with touch inputs. this is fixed in loki.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the process(wingpanel) stop. Even sometime application drawer won't work. I run this command. It will kill the current process and make it restart. Run this command line in your terminal.WinKey+T to open terminal. Paste this command and press enter. I hope this will solve your problem.

```
killall wingpanel
```

Comment: This Command solved my problem. I'm not posting here without experimenting. Let him try first. You just run this command on your system.

Comment: @DanielForé Agree with your comment :)

Comment: don't sweat it I got editor privs so I fixed it up. should he be allowed to plug his website? I'm sure you just wanna help people but I'm not so sure that tech support is the best way to promote your blog.

Comment: @Nine I removed that. Done :)